# Fetch data from database and use it in ng-repeat in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

In AngularJS, you can use ng-repeat to show each component of a list to HTML:

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="myctrl">
        <div ng-repeat="row in lists">
            <p>{{row.first}}</p>
            <p>{{row.last}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, in the above code, you have to write each component of a list first, which should be fetched from database manually before using it in the above HTML. So is there any way to directly fetch data from MySQL in Node.js and Express and render it to .ejs file, and then use the rendered list in AngularJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular runs on the client while Node runs on the server.  The code does not actually run together.  You could use ajax to get the data if you need:

```
// `lists` is returned as JSON
$http({url: url}).success(function (lists) {
    $scope.lists = lists;
});
```

You would do this without another page reload.  However, if the data already has to be queried and loaded with a server side run of the script, there is no benefit to have angular print out the list itself.  Instead you can just print it as part of the HTML directly.

Comment: The reason I want to use Angular is not just print the output of the list - I also want users to input text in search box and hence change the displayed result according to the user's input.